# How to use yammer's oauth2 from iOS?

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, yammer

I'm trying to get a iOS client to make use of Yammer's Oauth2 to validate a user. I first tried the GTM-OAuth2 code, but I cannot get it to understand the response from Yammer. It appears that the GTM code is expecting the access_code as a query parameter, where as Yammer is returning it as a uri fragment. I hack he GTM code to see the fragment, but now it appears to be thinking that there is an error because the code and message fields are not in the response from Yammer.

I've also tried to use OAuth2Client api but the problem there is that Yammer does not seem to want to use the redirect_uri I pass to it, so Safari never gets the custom url and therefore never calls back to the app.

Does anyone have a working example of using Yammer's OAuth2?

I would also be interested if anyone has got GTM-OAuth2 to work with Facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah Yammer has a shitty implementation of oAuth. Looks like each service has taken its own implementation of oauth. anyway yammer requires the user to copy a 4-digit code from its website, go back to your service paste that code in your website. Only then you can request for access code.

check this - http://www.tutorialjinni.com/2011/04/yammer-api-example.html (its in php but hope you can get the gist).

Nothing you can do about it but a fun read - [Yammer API sucks](http://pointbeing.net/weblog/2009/03/ways-in-which-the-yammer-api-sucks.html)

Comment: If someone is downvoting its common courtesy to say the reason for downvote.